# file handling: the code stops running

Tags: c++, c, file-handling

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen("a.text", "w+");

    int yes = 1, count = 0;

    char tree[30];

    while (yes) {
        printf("enter the name of the tree\n");
        scanf("%s", tree);
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", tree);
        printf("do you want to enter more  trees?enter 0 if no and 1 if yes\n");
        scanf("%d", &yes);
        count++;
    }

    char treeArr[count][30];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &treeArr[i]);
        printf("%s", treeArr[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

this part of the code is not working.

```
char treeArr[count][30];
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", &treeArr[i]);
    printf("%s", treeArr[i]);
}
```

I need to write the names of the trees in the file and and then put it into a string array, so that i can calculate the percentage of each tree.

this is the question. kindly provide a suitable solution.

1.As you walk along TU campus, you see lots of trees of different species on your way.

Horticulture Centre has prepared a list of every tree standing on the way from CSE Department to the Main Gate.

You have to report the percentage of each tree species.

**Input**

> Input to your program consists of a list of the species of every tree observed by the Horticulture Department; one tree per line in .txt file. No species name exceeds 30 characters.

**Output**

> Print the name of each tree species available in TU (sorted in order of their percentage), followed by the percentage of the population it represents.

Comment: I am sorry for your spacebar. Hope you get a new keyboard soon, so that you can reindent your code.

Comment: ^^^what @AnttiHaapala says.  Good formatting and indentation is not just a trivial matter of making code look pretty.  Poor indentation leads to flow-of-control and scoping bugs and, if you are posting your code to a Q&A site for help, tends to result in downvotes and closing as 'unclear':(

Answer (score 3):

Problem is your file pointer `fp` is pointing to the end of file after the `while` loop (where you write into the file). So the subsequent read operations (`fscanf`) going to return `EOF` immediately.

You can reset the file pointer to the beginning before reading the file:

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
```

You would have noticed this if error check your library calls (`fopen`, `scanf`, `fscanf`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

`%s` specifier expexts the `char*` but what you are passing is `char (*)[30]`. Even if they point to same memory they are different types.

Remove reference operator

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",treeArr[i]);
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Also you should rewind/reset file pointer of `fp` file descriptor which,after loop, point to the end of file what causes that `fscanf` returns EOF.

```
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
// Or
rewind(fp);
```